# Accessing XElement having namespace inside a parent with different namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I am having an xelement like this.

```
<fiAPI xmlns="http://integration.fiapi.com" xmlns:ITI="http://www.ITIWnet.com/" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlenc#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://integration.fiapi.com/fiAPI.xsd">
  <fiHeader Version="2.2">
    <Service Name="" Version="8.0">
      <DateTime>2015-04-23T16:09:39-05:00</DateTime>
      <UUID>d111bc1b-e539-47e6-93e0-d1c426346b78</UUID>
    </Service>
    <Security>
      <AuthenticationMaterial>
        <PrincipalPWD>
          <EncryptedData>
            <CipherData xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
              <CipherValue></CipherValue>
            </CipherData>
          </EncryptedData>
        </PrincipalPWD>
      </AuthenticationMaterial>
      <PrincipalID></PrincipalID>
      <TrustRelationship>User</TrustRelationship>
      <MessageDigest algorithm="SHA-1"></MessageDigest>
    </Security>
  </fiHeader>
</fiAPI>
```

i am trying to set some value to CipherValue tag like this.

```
var loginRequestNameSpace  = "http://integration.fiapi.com";
var cipherDataNameSpace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#";
XElement encryptedDataElement = loginRequestElement.Element(loginRequestNameSpace + "fiHeader").Element(loginRequestNameSpace + "Security").Element(loginRequestNameSpace + "AuthenticationMaterial").Element(loginRequestNameSpace + "PrincipalPWD").Element(loginRequestNameSpace + "EncryptedData");
XElement cypherDataElement = encryptedDataElement.Element(cipherDataNameSpace + "CipherData");
```

CipherData tag reads as NULL. I am doing something wrong with the namespace ?Can anybody help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a proper `XName` to correctly address the elements with different namespaces.

You can use the static method `XName.Get("fiHeader", loginRequestNameSpace)` for example instead of using string concatenation.